# PHP SplObjectStorage Cannot create within a class

Tags: php, oop, object, splobjectstorage

Would it be possible to initialize a protected `SplObjectStorage` as a map within a class? I seem to be running into an error whenever I try this. Similar to example below:

```
class a {

  protected $a = new SplObjectStorage();

  ...

}
```

Comment: You can only initialise a class property with a simple type or an array. It would be great to be able to do what you want, but this is another one of PHP's artificial limitations

Comment: You will have to initialize that inside the constructor.

Comment: You can't do this, but you may wish to consider injecting the inner instance into the outer one, so that it is not hard-wired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use constructor

```
class a {
  public function __construct() {
     $this->a = new SplObjectStorage();
  }

  protected $a;

  ...
}
```